# HttpURLConnection - "https://" vs. "http://"

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection, favicon

I'm trying to get the favicon of the url the user enters, for example

```
_url = "google.com";
```

I use HttpUrlConnection to get the Bitmap of the favicon from the `/favicon.ico` extension from the host url.

```
        String faviconString = Uri.parse(_url).getHost() + "/favicon.ico";
        URL faviconUrl = null;
        Bitmap favicon = null;
        try
        {
            faviconString = "http://" + faviconString;
            faviconUrl = new URL(faviconString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) faviconUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            favicon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return favicon;
```

However, since the user probably won't specify `http://` or `https://`, I would have to add it myself. The problem I'm having is that, if I add `http://` in front of the url, everything would work fine, but for `https://`, some sites would return the favicon, others would just give me null. How do I find out which page uses `https`? Should I just add `http://` for every case? Are there any websites that restricts to strictly `https` and would return null for using `http`?

Comment: This is not an extremely reliable technique since favicons might be defined inside the page like this `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/a/different/path.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

Comment: Is there any other ways you would suggest? `WebIconDatabase` and `WebView.getFavicon()` would be ideal but `WebIconDatabase` is deprecated

Comment: Sorry I'm not that familiar with android, but that sounds like a pretty good approach.

Comment: Hint: in addition to the above, some websites might return null for http and work on https

Comment: @SherifelKhatib that's essentially what this question is about

Comment: @JasonHu You just edited your question to say that's essentially what this question is about! I was referring to the fact that a website may choose to serve one of the 2 schemes or both. And my comment is way before your edit!

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I just added the bit at the end to clarify the question. If I didn't know that `http` would return null, why would I even bother with `https`, why would I even bother asking this question.

Comment: `Should I just add http:// for every case?` was why I said what I said. Anyway, it is very unrealistic to hardcode this `Uri.parse(_url).getHost() + "/favicon.ico"`. However if you insist on getting only this path, you can do a HEAD request to know details about the resource without even getting the data. check it here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4

Comment: @SherifelKhatib that sounds good. It's just that I'm always hesitant to do things manually when in actuality there's probably something in the android API that handles it which I wasn't aware of hence the questions :(

Comment: @JasonHu, in the case where you're getting `null` back, what is the HTTP status code? have you checked to see if its a 404, or a redirect, or something else? If its a redirect, is the API you're using following them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you use user2558882's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972329/42962) or there is some other tool out in the wild that will just get a websites favicon for you, you're going to have to check both the http and https urls.  There is no other way to do this.  It is part of the difficulty of using the web.

Perhaps looking at your code differently and breaking down what you're trying to do into smaller more manageable parts would be a bit better?

```
public void getFavicon(String host) {

    URL httpUrl = this.getHttpUrl(host + "/favicon.ico");

    Bitmap favicon = this.getBitmap(httpUrl);

    if (favicon == null) {

        URL httpsUrl = this.getHttpsUrl(host + "/favicon.ico");

        favicon = this.getBitmap(httpsUrl);
    }

    if (favicon == null) {

        throw new FaviconMissingException("Unable to find favicon for host: " + host);
    }

    return favicon;
}

public URL getHttpUrl(String uri) throws MalformedURLException {

    // There are better ways of building a url then string concationation.
    return new URL("http://" + uri);
}

public URL getHttpsUrl(String uri) throws MalformedURLException {

    // There are better ways of building a url then string concationation.
    return new URL("https://" + uri);
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(URL url) {

    InputStream inputStream = getInputStream(url);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

    return bitmap
}

public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {

    // Please use a real connection library like HTTPClient here!
    // HttpClient will handle timeouts, redirects, and things like that for you.
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();

    return connection.getInputStream();
}
```

BTW, being concerned about one or two connections takes more time then writing the code to make two requests.  I almost guarantee that google is making two requests as needed.  And if it is good enough for google it is good enough for me.

Finally, if you start to see that making two requests is really taking too much time, then do something about improving the performance.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I am not sure how helpful my answer would be.

You can grab the favicon using google:

```
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=stackoverflow.com
```

returns:

[image]

You don't have to specify `http` or `https`.

```
 http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=my.yorku.ca ===>> (https://my.yorku.ca)
```

returns:

[image]

But this is not the actual favicon that https://my.yorku.ca uses. So, I guess google returns a default one for sites that do not provide access their favicons.

```
InputStream is = null;

String urlPrefix = "http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=";

String _url = "google.com";

Bitmap favicon = null;

try {

    is = (InputStream) new URL(urlPrefix + _url).getContent();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

favicon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

You can actually keep a copy of the default favicon and check if:

```
if (defaultBitmap.sameAs(favicon)) {
    // favicon wasn't available
}
```

Comment: This is a cool approach, but for the yorku example, `yorku.com/favicon.ico` does return the correct favicon. So I'll probably still go with `/favicon.ico` alternative.

Comment: @JasonHu Just want to make sure that you're using valid test cases. `yorku.com/favicon.ico` isn't valid, the domain is `http://yorku.ca`. In my answer, I used `https://my.yorku.ca`. When I tried using `https://my.yorku.ca/favicon.ico`, I got a null value. The google approach works just fine for `yorku.ca`.

Comment: My bad in the first comment, I did use `yorku.ca` in my test that worked. I think getting back `null` is fine, unless for a case where using `/favicon.ico` gives back `null` and `google` gives back something that's not the default icon. When I get back `null` I'm just using a default icon on my end too

Comment: @JasonHu Yes, both approaches work for `yorku.ca`. But the google approach does not work for `my.yorku.ca`. Does your approach work for it?

Comment: Nope, it returns `null` in which case I'll just display a default favicon on my end

Comment: @JasonHu Try with `_url = eff.org`. The google url will return the favicon, while `/favicon.ico` will return null. So I guess you should find a case where: the google approach breaks and `/favicon.ico` works.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if the website returns null or a favicon?

I hope this helps you

Comment: You mean try `https://` first and check if the favicon returned is `null` and then try `http://`? That's kind of brute forced, I'd rather not proceed that way if possible. After all it would require me to open the connection twice which is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that is even 'easier'.

Just make the user enter the url (including protocol) for their favicon and validate that url returns a favicon.  If not then display a validation error back to the end user.

Following agile principals, do the least amount of work and see what works.  If the one plan doesn't work, then try something different.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when URL start with "https":

```
              TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
               {
                 new X509TrustManager()
                  {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()  { return null; }
                    public void checkClientTrusted( java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)  {}
                    public void checkServerTrusted( java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)  {}
                  }
                 };
              try
                {
                  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL"); // "TLS" "SSL"
                  sc.init( null, trustAllCerts, null);
                  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory( sc.getSocketFactory());
                  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier( 
                   new HostnameVerifier() 
                    {
                      public boolean verify( String hostname, SSLSession session) { return true; }
                    } );
                }
               catch( Exception e)
```